# Can I toggle "Use All My Monitors For Remote Sessions" when on RDP without disconnecting and re-connecting?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I sometimes need my RDP session to use both my monitors, and sometimes I need the RDP session to use one monitor and the local to use the other. But to toggle I need to disconnect first and then check/uncheck "Use All My Monitors For Remote Sessions" and then connect again. Is there any way to change the RDP session to use both my monitors without reconnecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported. You have to disconnect, check the box and reconnect.

The reason is a bit more complicated, but the main idea is that you are attaching multiple monitors to the remote host over RDP, which is not supported.

Comment: Not quite: if you disconnect a physical monitor on a client, then the server will correctly respond to that and reconfigure its desktop. Rather the devs were too lazy to add a button